# Unable to store image from MySQL into PHP array

Tags: php

I'm trying to store the image into an array. My php code as below:

```
$query_search1 = "SELECT profilePicture FROM rocket WHERE username='".$rocketName."'";
$query_exec1 = mysqli_query($db->getConnection(),$query_search1) or die(mysqli_error($db->getConnection()));
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_exec1);
//$rocketPic = $row1['profilePicture'];
$json = array();

//$json['rocket_profile'][] = $row1;
if(mysqli_num_rows($query_exec1)){
    while($row2 = $row1){
        $json['rocket_profile'][] = $row2;
    }
}
```

Data type for profilePicture is BLOB. Below is the error I got:

```
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes)
```

All I want is to store it as json to be used in Android application.

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite while loop. This consume all your RAM mem. Review your loop logic.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinity loop, try this:

```
$query_search1 = "SELECT profilePicture FROM rocket WHERE username='".$rocketName."'";
$query_exec1 = mysqli_query($db->getConnection(),$query_search1) or die(mysqli_error($db->getConnection()));
$json = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($query_exec1)){
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_exec1)){
        $json['rocket_profile'][] = $row1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this. But it's not displaying anything when I tried to run the php file. Can I actually store a BLOB data into json just like that ?

Comment: @SOFT1234 For why you are use BLOB for store text? May be best way - use other filed type for this, TEXT for example? [Here](http://myvedham.blogspot.ru/2013/10/read-blob-from-mysql.html) you can read "how-to convert blob to text".

Comment: it's not a text. its an image.

Comment: @SOFT1234 in your first post you talk "All I want is to store it as json to be used in Android application." Json is not image, it's text. [Here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-blob/) sample with image blob, or others links from google...

Answer (score 0):

You can set `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` before your `$query_search1` variable to solve the error :`Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes)`

But I suggest you to check your logic instead of change the Resources memory Limit. :)